# Chart.js stacked bar chart iterate over datasets

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hello,
I am pretty new in the js world.
I have an issue with a stacked bar chart in chart.js.
The problem is, how can I iterate over the datasets?

I hardcoded the chart and it works, but if there are any changes in the futures I am screwed.
I already tried for loops but achieved nothing working.

I also added this funktion, but I'm not sure where to call it in the chart.

Thank you so much for your help!!!!

```
function updateChart() {
    for (let index = 0; index < data.generation.length; index++) {
        chart.data.datasets[index].label = data.genration[index];
        chart.data.datasets[index].backgroundColor = colors[index];
        chart.data.datasets[index].data = data.quantity[index];
    }
    chart.update();
};
```

Here is the code:

```
<script>
```

var colors = ['#8CA6B3', '#87C488', '#AA641E', '#D7CBBD', '#284651', '#C1893F', '#AF8F90', '#69454F', '#A8DFF1', '#085438' ];

```
$(function () {
    var $ppChart = $("#data_pp");
    $.ajax({
        url: $ppChart.data("url"),
        success: function (data) {
            var ctx = $ppChart[0].getContext("2d");
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: data.month,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: data.generation[0],
                        backgroundColor: colors[0],
                        data: data.quantity[0],
                    }, 
                    {
                        label: data.generation[1],
                        backgroundColor: colors[1],
                        data: data.quantity[1],
                    }, 
                    {
                        label: data.generation[2],
                        backgroundColor: colors[2],
                        data: data.quantity[2],
                    }, 
                    {
                        label: data.generation[3],
                        backgroundColor: colors[3],
                        data: data.quantity[3],
                    },
                    {
                        label: data.generation[4],
                        backgroundColor: colors[4],
                        data: data.quantity[4],
                    },
                    {
                        label: data.generation[5],
                        backgroundColor: colors[5],
                        data: data.quantity[5],
                    },
                    {
                        label: data.generation[6],
                        backgroundColor: colors[6],
                        data: data.quantity[6],
                    },
                    {
                        label: data.generation[7],
                        backgroundColor: colors[7],
                        data: data.quantity[7],
                    },
                    {
                        label: data.generation[8],
                        backgroundColor: colors[8],
                        data: data.quantity[8],
                    },
                    {
                        label: data.generation[9],
                        backgroundColor: colors[9],
                        data: data.quantity[9],
                    },
                    {
                        label: data.generation[10],
                        backgroundColor: colors[10],
                        data: data.quantity[10],
                    }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            stacked: true
                        }],
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true
                        }]
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    legend: {
                        position: 'top',
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
});

 function updateChart() {
    for (let index = 0; index < data.generation.length; index++) {
        chart.data.datasets[index].label = data.generation[index];
        chart.data.datasets[index].backgroundColor = colors[index];
        chart.data.datasets[index].data = data.quantity[index];
    }
    chart.update();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling only new Chart, put it in a variable:

```
var chart = new Chart();
```

and then you can access all the datasets in the chart variable like this: `chart.data.datasets`. This will give an array containing all datasets you have in your chart which you can loop over

Comment: Hello LeeLenalee,
Thanks a lot for your answer.
I found a some related examples in the documentation.
I created a function, but I'm not sure where to implement it.